# React input field for both email and text

Tags: reactjs, html-input, react-forms

**The flow I want to achieve:**

1. User types in an email
2. It's validated
3. User decides to remove the "@...com" part (type changes from "email" to "text")
4. All that is done with cursor remaining in its place.

**What's happening now:**

Following React input component re-focuses itself and moves cursor to the front each time after text type change:

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-bootstrap4-form-validation';
...
  const [inputType, setInputType] = useState("text");
...
  const onSearchChange = (search) => {
    setInputType(search.target.value && search.target.value.includes("@") ? "email" : "text");
  }

<>
   <TextInput
    key="editor1"
    name={inputType}
    id="input-with-icon-grid"
    type={inputType}
    placeholder="Email / ID /"
    required
    validator={() => inputType === "email" ? validator.isEmail : true}
    autoComplete="false"
    errorMessage={{ validator: "Please enter a valid email" }}
    value={searchFor}
    onChange={(e) => onSearchChange(e)}
   />
</>
```

**Question:**

Has anyone dealt with this use case and are there better React components available?